# Magmi Price Change for Magento

Tags: magento, csv, magmi

I am using UnderstandingE's version of Magmi.

I use Magmi to automatically import a CSV file from our supplier. The supplier's CSV has a column that says the price that we will pay to our supplier - "wholesale_price."

But that is not the price that we want to display on our site. So we want Magmi to create a column for "price." The value should be something like (wholesale_price * 130%). Is this something we can do with Magmi?

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is

use value replacer plugin , advanced syntax , there is a [sample](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Value_Replacer#Advanced_Syntax_examples) that calculates price for cost column.

Of course, you can use any column , so in your case:

for attribute to replace , enter : **price**  <= this is the value you want to set

the formula to use would be:

```
{{ {item.wholesale_price}*1.30 }}
```

above is a formula for calculating the price according to your need.